# Show a text value after making a selection in a drop down box

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html

I'm building a web-app that allows people to select their US state from a drop-down box, displaying a telephone number for that area, however I'm having some difficulty doing so.

I've built the rest of the site in PHP and realise that this is a client side action, so I'd need to use JavaScript or Jquery.

Each state has a different number, so for example when Columbia is select I want to show the number for Columbia in a div next to the text box.

The values can be stored in a MySQL database if needed.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: This kind of stuff happens all over the place.  It's common and doesn't need to be client-side, though client-side is easier to program.  Regardless, show your code.

Comment: @vol7ron, I think, you mean "doesn't need to be _server-side_" :)

Comment: @Phillip: no, it can be done server-side, hence the `though client-side is easier to program`.  Doing it client-side is quicker on the effect, requires less network traffic, and all-around is the web2.0 choice

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you pull the data out to put into the drop down box store the telephone number as the 'value' of each option.

Then you can just set the `div` text to be `$('getCheckBox').val()`.

Answer (score -1):

```
$('dropdown').change(function(){
    id = $(this).val();
    myFucntionDoToWhateverIwantItToDo(id);
});

function myFucntionDoToWhateverIwantItToDo(id){
    // Do stuff in the div, baby. The ID is stored in id.
    $("div").empty().append(id);
}
```

Obviously replace `dropdown` and `div` with their real `ids` or `classes`